# Dynamically Nested Menu - Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to create a "Dynamic Nested Menu" with Angular Material.
I Created this one ,
It's work but its have three problems:
1- It's ugly :(
2- Only 3 layer
3- It's not dynamic (i have to update html and add one more layer)
idk what to say anymore : It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
This is My Menu HTML:

```html
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="rootMenu">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <!-- [Start] Root Menu -->
  <mat-menu #rootMenu="matMenu">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let cat of categories">
      <div *ngIf="cat.children">
        <div *ngIf="cat.children.length > 0">
          <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="subMenu">{{cat.name}}</button>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!cat.children.length">
          <button mat-menu-item>{{cat.name}}</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- [Start] Sub Menu -->
      <mat-menu #subMenu="matMenu">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let child of cat.children">
          <div *ngIf="child.children">
            <div *ngIf="child.children.length > 0">
              <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="subChildMenu"> {{child.name}}</button>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!child.children.length">
              <button mat-menu-item>{{child.name}}</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- [Start] SubChild Menu -->
          <mat-menu #subChildMenu="matMenu">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let zxc of child.children">
              <button mat-menu-item> {{zxc.name}} </button>
            </ng-container>
          </mat-menu>
          <!-- [End] SubChild Menu -->

        </ng-container>
      </mat-menu>
      <!-- [End] Sub Menu -->

    </ng-container>
  </mat-menu>
  <!-- [End] Root Menu -->
```

This is my Data (i'm using graphql)

```
{
  "data": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "name": "App",
        "child": [
          {
            "name": "Power",
            "child": [
              {
                "name": "Light",
                "child": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Cable",
                "child": []
              },
              {
                "name": "Others",
                "child": [
                  {
                    "name": "Alerts"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is tree of my data

```
└───App
    └───Power
        ├───Cable
        ├───Light
        └───Others
            └───Alerts
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the awsome [tree component](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples) that comes with angular material, it looks cool and it's dynamic! also, the code is pretty flexible.
Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks , i didn't know there is something like that. :*

Comment: You welcome, please mark it as correct if that's helped.

Comment: I would advice using angular material components a lot, This library is truly compatible with angular and it can fasten the development time a lot, it's also easy to learn and deal with, give it a chance ;)

Comment: thank you for advice , i'll definitely use it 
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. "

Comment: No,The (mark as correct is different) and it do affect my reputation, please follow these instructions:
To accept an answer: Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."